# Greenplum Transpose rows into columns

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I need to tranform this table:

| dt | user_name | call_type | call_start | call_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | Bob | in | 2023-01-01 10:00:00.000 | 2023-01-01 10:05:00.000 |
| 2023-01-01 | Bob | in | 2023-01-01 11:00:00.000 | 2023-01-01 11:05:00.000 |
| 2023-01-01 | Bob | out | 2023-01-01 09:00:00.000 | 2023-01-01 09:05:00.000 |
| 2023-01-01 | Tom | out | 2023-01-02 09:00:00.000 | 2023-01-02 09:05:00.000 |

to this variant

| dt | user_name | out_call_start | out_call_end | out_min | in_call_start | in_call_end | in_min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | Bob | 2023-01-01 09:00:00.000 | 2023-01-01 09:05:00.000 | 00:05:00 | 2023-01-01 11:00:00.000 | 2023-01-01 11:05:00.000 | 00:05:00 |
| 2023-01-01 | Bob | 2023-01-01 09:00:00.000 | 2023-01-01 09:05:00.000 | 00:05:00 | 2023-01-01 10:00:00.000 | 2023-01-01 10:05:00.000 | 00:05:00 |
| 2023-01-01 | Tom | 2023-01-02 09:00:00.000 | 2023-01-02 09:05:00.000 | 00:05:00 |  |  |  |

In other words call_start and call_end columns store the beginning and the end of calls of different types. And I want to show these dates as columns and show the beginning and the end of each call type in the table.

This is how I try to do it:

```
create table users_actions
(dt date, 
user_name text, 
call_type text, 
call_start timestamp without time zone, 
call_end timestamp without time zone)
 
insert into  users_actions values
('2023-01-01','Bob','in','2023-01-01 10:00:00','2023-01-01 10:05:00'),
('2023-01-01','Bob','in','2023-01-01 11:00:00','2023-01-01 11:05:00'),
('2023-01-01','Bob','out','2023-01-01 09:00:00','2023-01-01 09:05:00'),
('2023-01-01','Tom','out','2023-01-02 09:00:00','2023-01-02 09:05:00')

create table agg as 
select dt,user_name,call_type, call_end, call_start,sum(call_end-call_start) as call_min from users_actions
group by dt,user_name,call_type,  call_start, call_end


create table users  as
select  dt, user_name
from users_actions
group by dt, user_name

create table horizontal_users_actions as
select 
  u.dt
, u.user_name
, a.call_start as out_call_start
, a.call_end as  out_call_end
, a.call_min as  out_min
, a2.call_start as in_call_start
, a2.call_end as  in_call_end
, a2.call_min as  in_min
from users u
left join agg as a on u.user_name = a.user_name
and a.call_type = 'out'
left join agg as a2 on  a.user_name = a2.user_name
and  a2.call_type = 'in'

--select * from users_actions
--select * from users
--select * from agg
--select * from horizontal_users_actions
```

Is there any more optimosed ways to achieve the same result?
Thank you.